# Azure Traffice Manager External End Points

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-traffic-manager

Can someone explain to me how to setup a external end point for a fail over model in Windows Azure Traffic manager. I can add the end point to azure through powershell, for example www.mysite.com, but then the tutorials say I would need to change my DNS to point www.mysite.com to my.trafficmanager.net. But wouldnt this create a loop of sorts and never get to my actual server that is hosting the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you describe you would first need to define a new hostname for your external endpoint in DNS (i.e. www-1.mysite.com) and configure your webserver to accept requests for that hostname.  Once that is working you add the www-1.mysite.com to Traffic Manager as an external endpoint and the finally update DNS for www.mysite.com to point to Traffic Manager.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I configure it so mysite.com responds as well as www.mysite.com?

Comment: @matt depends on the web server you are using, if you use IIS go into IIS manager, pick the site and then click on "Bindings" (Ms Documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @Paul I meant through the traffic manager. If I have a www cname that goes to my.trafficmanager.net that is the only thing that will be routed through traffic manager. How do I setup the DNS so the parent level domain goes to the traffic manager as well? Can I have a cname for the parent level that points to the traffic manager?

Comment: You can't setup a CNAME for an apex domain name (ie. mysite.com). Your domain name registrar should have a forwarding option to forward DNS lookups to mysite.com to www.mysite.com.